# checkout onepage controller error

Tags: onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, billing

I have created a module to remove the shipping method from the checkout page..

after doing everything  i have got this error 
`preParse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public'`(T_PUBLIC)`in`\htdocs\app\code\local\Paypalextended\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php`on line 3`81

these are the codes

```
`<?php
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php';
class Paypalextended_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_Controller_Action
{
   /**
     * List of functions for section update
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_sectionUpdateFunctions = array(
        'payment-method'  => '_getPaymentMethodsHtml',
        'shipping-method' => '_getShippingMethodsHtml',
        'review'          => '_getReviewHtml',
    );

    /**
     * @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order
     */
    protected $_order;

    /**
     * Predispatch: should set layout area
     *
     * @return Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
     */
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        parent::preDispatch();
        $this->_preDispatchValidateCustomer();

        $checkoutSessionQuote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        if ($checkoutSessionQuote->getIsMultiShipping()) {
            $checkoutSessionQuote->setIsMultiShipping(false);
            $checkoutSessionQuote->removeAllAddresses();
        }

        if (!$this->_canShowForUnregisteredUsers()) {
            $this->norouteAction();
            $this->setFlag('',self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH,true);
            return;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Send Ajax redirect response
     *
     * @return Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
     */
    protected function _ajaxRedirectResponse()
    {
        $this->getResponse()
            ->setHeader('HTTP/1.1', '403 Session Expired')
            ->setHeader('Login-Required', 'true')
            ->sendResponse();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Validate ajax request and redirect on failure
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _expireAjax()
    {
        if (!$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->hasItems()
            || $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getHasError()
            || $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getIsMultiShipping()
        ) {
            $this->_ajaxRedirectResponse();
            return true;
        }
        $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
        if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getCartWasUpdated(true)
            && !in_array($action, array('index', 'progress'))
        ) {
            $this->_ajaxRedirectResponse();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get shipping method step html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getShippingMethodsHtml()
    {
        $layout = $this->getLayout();
        $update = $layout->getUpdate();
        $update->load('checkout_onepage_shippingmethod');
        $layout->generateXml();
        $layout->generateBlocks();
        $output = $layout->getOutput();
        return $output;
    }

    /**
     * Get payment method step html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getPaymentMethodsHtml()
    {
        $layout = $this->getLayout();
        $update = $layout->getUpdate();
        $update->load('checkout_onepage_paymentmethod');
        $layout->generateXml();
        $layout->generateBlocks();
        $output = $layout->getOutput();
        return $output;
    }

    /**
     * Return block content from the 'checkout_onepage_additional'
     * This is the additional content for shipping method
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getAdditionalHtml()
    {
        $layout = $this->getLayout();
        $update = $layout->getUpdate();
        $update->load('checkout_onepage_additional');
        $layout->generateXml();
        $layout->generateBlocks();
        $output = $layout->getOutput();
        Mage::getSingleton('core/translate_inline')->processResponseBody($output);
        return $output;
    }

    /**
     * Get order review step html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getReviewHtml()
    {
        return $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Get one page checkout model
     *
     * @return Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage
     */
    public function getOnepage()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
    }

    /**
     * Checkout page
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        if (!Mage::helper('checkout')->canOnepageCheckout()) {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($this->__('The onepage checkout is disabled.'));
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }
        $quote = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote();
        if (!$quote->hasItems() || $quote->getHasError()) {
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }
        if (!$quote->validateMinimumAmount()) {
            $error = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/error_message') ?
                Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/error_message') :
                Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Subtotal must exceed minimum order amount');

            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($error);
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(false);
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_secure' => true)));
        $this->getOnepage()->initCheckout();
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Checkout'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Refreshes the previous step
     * Loads the block corresponding to the current step and sets it
     * in to the response body
     *
     * This function is called from the reloadProgessBlock
     * function from the javascript
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function progressAction()
    {
        // previous step should never be null. We always start with billing and go forward
        $prevStep = $this->getRequest()->getParam('prevStep', false);

        if ($this->_expireAjax() || !$prevStep) {
            return null;
        }

        $layout = $this->getLayout();
        $update = $layout->getUpdate();
        /* Load the block belonging to the current step*/
        $update->load('checkout_onepage_progress_' . $prevStep);
        $layout->generateXml();
        $layout->generateBlocks();
        $output = $layout->getOutput();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($output);
        return $output;
    }

    /**
     * Shipping method action
     */
    public function shippingMethodAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }
        $this->loadLayout(false);
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Review page action
     */
    public function reviewAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }
        $this->loadLayout(false);
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Order success action
     */
    public function successAction()
    {
        $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
        if (!$session->getLastSuccessQuoteId()) {
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }

        $lastQuoteId = $session->getLastQuoteId();
        $lastOrderId = $session->getLastOrderId();
        $lastRecurringProfiles = $session->getLastRecurringProfileIds();
        if (!$lastQuoteId || (!$lastOrderId && empty($lastRecurringProfiles))) {
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }

        $session->clear();
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Failure action
     */
    public function failureAction()
    {
        $lastQuoteId = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getLastQuoteId();
        $lastOrderId = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getLastOrderId();

        if (!$lastQuoteId || !$lastOrderId) {
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }


    /**
     * Get additional info action
     */
    public function getAdditionalAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->_getAdditionalHtml());
    }

    /**
     * Address JSON
     */
    public function getAddressAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }
        $addressId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('address', false);
        if ($addressId) {
            $address = $this->getOnepage()->getAddress($addressId);

            if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId() == $address->getCustomerId()) {
                $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-json');
                $this->getResponse()->setBody($address->toJson());
            } else {
                $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','403 Forbidden');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save checkout method
     */
    public function saveMethodAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $method = $this->getRequest()->getPost('method');
            $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveCheckoutMethod($method);
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save checkout billing address
     */
    public function saveBillingAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
            $customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing_address_id', false);

            if (isset($data['email'])) {
                $data['email'] = trim($data['email']);
            }
            $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId);

             if (!isset($result['error'])) {

                $method = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';
                $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveShippingMethod($method);
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()-> setShippingMethod($method)->save();

            if (!isset($result['error'])) {
                if ($this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
                    $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                    $result['update_section'] = array(
                        'name' => 'payment-method',
                        'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                    );
                } elseif (isset($data['use_for_shipping']) && $data['use_for_shipping'] == 1) {
                        $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                        $result['update_section'] = array(
                        'name' => 'payment-method',
                        'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                        );

                    $result['allow_sections'] = array('shipping');
                    $result['duplicateBillingInfo'] = 'true';
                } else {
                    $result['goto_section'] = 'shipping';
                }
            }

            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shipping address save action
     */
    public function saveShippingAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping', array());
            $customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_address_id', false);
            $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveShipping($data, $customerAddressId);

            if (!isset($result['error'])) {
            $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
            $result['update_section'] = array(
            'name' => 'payment-method',
            'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
        );
         }
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shipping method save action
     */
    public function saveShippingMethodAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_method', '');
            $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveShippingMethod($data);
            // $result will contain error data if shipping method is empty
            if (!$result) {
                Mage::dispatchEvent(
                    'checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method',
                     array(
                          'request' => $this->getRequest(),
                          'quote'   => $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()));
                $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals();
                $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));

                $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                $result['update_section'] = array(
                    'name' => 'payment-method',
                    'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                );
            }
            $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save payment ajax action
     *
     * Sets either redirect or a JSON response
     */
    public function savePaymentAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
                $this->_ajaxRedirectResponse();
                return;
            }

            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('payment', array());
            $result = $this->getOnepage()->savePayment($data);

            // get section and redirect data
            $redirectUrl = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getPayment()->getCheckoutRedirectUrl();
            if (empty($result['error']) && !$redirectUrl) {
                $this->loadLayout('checkout_onepage_review');
                $result['goto_section'] = 'review';
                $result['update_section'] = array(
                    'name' => 'review',
                    'html' => $this->_getReviewHtml()
                );
            }
            if ($redirectUrl) {
                $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
            }
        } catch (Mage_Payment_Exception $e) {
            if ($e->getFields()) {
                $result['fields'] = $e->getFields();
            }
            $result['error'] = $e->getMessage();
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $result['error'] = $e->getMessage();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            $result['error'] = $this->__('Unable to set Payment Method.');
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }

    /**
     * Get Order by quoteId
     *
     * @throws Mage_Payment_Model_Info_Exception
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order
     */
    protected function _getOrder()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_order)) {
            $this->_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getId(), 'quote_id');
            if (!$this->_order->getId()) {
                throw new Mage_Payment_Model_Info_Exception(Mage::helper('core')->__("Can not create invoice. Order was not found."));
            }
        }
        return $this->_order;
    }

    /**
     * Create invoice
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice
     */
    protected function _initInvoice()
    {
        $items = array();
        foreach ($this->_getOrder()->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $items[$item->getId()] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
        }
        /* @var $invoice Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Order */
        $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $this->_getOrder())->prepareInvoice($items);
        $invoice->setEmailSent(true)->register();

        Mage::register('current_invoice', $invoice);
        return $invoice;
    }

    /**
     * Create order action
     */
    public function saveOrderAction()
    {
        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*');
            return;
        }

        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }

        $result = array();
        try {
            $requiredAgreements = Mage::helper('checkout')->getRequiredAgreementIds();
            if ($requiredAgreements) {
                $postedAgreements = array_keys($this->getRequest()->getPost('agreement', array()));
                $diff = array_diff($requiredAgreements, $postedAgreements);
                if ($diff) {
                    $result['success'] = false;
                    $result['error'] = true;
                    $result['error_messages'] = $this->__('Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order.');
                    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
                    return;
                }
            }

            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('payment', array());
            if ($data) {
                $data['checks'] = Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_USE_CHECKOUT
                    | Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_USE_FOR_COUNTRY
                    | Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_USE_FOR_CURRENCY
                    | Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_ORDER_TOTAL_MIN_MAX
                    | Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_ZERO_TOTAL;
                $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getPayment()->importData($data);
            }

            $this->getOnepage()->saveOrder();

            $redirectUrl = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getRedirectUrl();
            $result['success'] = true;
            $result['error']   = false;
        } catch (Mage_Payment_Model_Info_Exception $e) {
            $message = $e->getMessage();
            if (!empty($message)) {
                $result['error_messages'] = $message;
            }
            $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
            $result['update_section'] = array(
                'name' => 'payment-method',
                'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
            );
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            Mage::helper('checkout')->sendPaymentFailedEmail($this->getOnepage()->getQuote(), $e->getMessage());
            $result['success'] = false;
            $result['error'] = true;
            $result['error_messages'] = $e->getMessage();

            $gotoSection = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getGotoSection();
            if ($gotoSection) {
                $result['goto_section'] = $gotoSection;
                $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->setGotoSection(null);
            }
            $updateSection = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getUpdateSection();
            if ($updateSection) {
                if (isset($this->_sectionUpdateFunctions[$updateSection])) {
                    $updateSectionFunction = $this->_sectionUpdateFunctions[$updateSection];
                    $result['update_section'] = array(
                        'name' => $updateSection,
                        'html' => $this->$updateSectionFunction()
                    );
                }
                $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->setUpdateSection(null);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            Mage::helper('checkout')->sendPaymentFailedEmail($this->getOnepage()->getQuote(), $e->getMessage());
            $result['success']  = false;
            $result['error']    = true;
            $result['error_messages'] = $this->__('There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later.');
        }
        $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();
        /**
         * when there is redirect to third party, we don't want to save order yet.
         * we will save the order in return action.
         */
        if (isset($redirectUrl)) {
            $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
        }

        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }

    /**
     * Filtering posted data. Converting localized data if needed
     *
     * @param array
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _filterPostData($data)
    {
        $data = $this->_filterDates($data, array('dob'));
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Check can page show for unregistered users
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _canShowForUnregisteredUsers()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()
            || $this->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'index'
            || Mage::helper('checkout')->isAllowedGuestCheckout($this->getOnepage()->getQuote())
            || !Mage::helper('checkout')->isCustomerMustBeLogged();
}
```

}`

Answer (score 1):

Try below code of yours:

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php';
class Paypalextended_Checkout_OnepageController extends 
Mage_Checkout_Controller_Action
{
 /**
 * List of functions for section update
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_sectionUpdateFunctions = array(
    'payment-method'  => '_getPaymentMethodsHtml',
    'shipping-method' => '_getShippingMethodsHtml',
    'review'          => '_getReviewHtml',
);

/**
 * @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order
 */
protected $_order;

/**
 * Predispatch: should set layout area
 *
 * @return Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
 */
public function preDispatch()
{
    parent::preDispatch();
    $this->_preDispatchValidateCustomer();

    $checkoutSessionQuote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    if ($checkoutSessionQuote->getIsMultiShipping()) {
        $checkoutSessionQuote->setIsMultiShipping(false);
        $checkoutSessionQuote->removeAllAddresses();
    }

    if (!$this->_canShowForUnregisteredUsers()) {
        $this->norouteAction();
        $this->setFlag('',self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH,true);
        return;
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Send Ajax redirect response
 *
 * @return Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
 */
protected function _ajaxRedirectResponse()
{
    $this->getResponse()
        ->setHeader('HTTP/1.1', '403 Session Expired')
        ->setHeader('Login-Required', 'true')
        ->sendResponse();
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Validate ajax request and redirect on failure
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _expireAjax()
{
    if (!$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->hasItems()
        || $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getHasError()
        || $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getIsMultiShipping()
    ) {
        $this->_ajaxRedirectResponse();
        return true;
    }
    $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
    if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getCartWasUpdated(true)
        && !in_array($action, array('index', 'progress'))
    ) {
        $this->_ajaxRedirectResponse();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Get shipping method step html
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getShippingMethodsHtml()
{
    $layout = $this->getLayout();
    $update = $layout->getUpdate();
    $update->load('checkout_onepage_shippingmethod');
    $layout->generateXml();
    $layout->generateBlocks();
    $output = $layout->getOutput();
    return $output;
}

/**
 * Get payment method step html
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getPaymentMethodsHtml()
{
    $layout = $this->getLayout();
    $update = $layout->getUpdate();
    $update->load('checkout_onepage_paymentmethod');
    $layout->generateXml();
    $layout->generateBlocks();
    $output = $layout->getOutput();
    return $output;
}

/**
 * Return block content from the 'checkout_onepage_additional'
 * This is the additional content for shipping method
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getAdditionalHtml()
{
    $layout = $this->getLayout();
    $update = $layout->getUpdate();
    $update->load('checkout_onepage_additional');
    $layout->generateXml();
    $layout->generateBlocks();
    $output = $layout->getOutput();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/translate_inline')->processResponseBody($output);
    return $output;
}

/**
 * Get order review step html
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getReviewHtml()
{
    return $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->toHtml();
}

/**
 * Get one page checkout model
 *
 * @return Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage
 */
public function getOnepage()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
}

/**
 * Checkout page
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    if (!Mage::helper('checkout')->canOnepageCheckout()) {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($this->__('The onepage checkout is disabled.'));
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }
    $quote = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote();
    if (!$quote->hasItems() || $quote->getHasError()) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }
    if (!$quote->validateMinimumAmount()) {
        $error = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/error_message') ?
            Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/error_message') :
            Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Subtotal must exceed minimum order amount');

        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($error);
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(false);
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_secure' => true)));
    $this->getOnepage()->initCheckout();
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Checkout'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}

/**
 * Refreshes the previous step
 * Loads the block corresponding to the current step and sets it
 * in to the response body
 *
 * This function is called from the reloadProgessBlock
 * function from the javascript
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
public function progressAction()
{
    // previous step should never be null. We always start with billing and go forward
    $prevStep = $this->getRequest()->getParam('prevStep', false);

    if ($this->_expireAjax() || !$prevStep) {
        return null;
    }

    $layout = $this->getLayout();
    $update = $layout->getUpdate();
    /* Load the block belonging to the current step*/
    $update->load('checkout_onepage_progress_' . $prevStep);
    $layout->generateXml();
    $layout->generateBlocks();
    $output = $layout->getOutput();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($output);
    return $output;
}

/**
 * Shipping method action
 */
public function shippingMethodAction()
{
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }
    $this->loadLayout(false);
    $this->renderLayout();
}

/**
 * Review page action
 */
public function reviewAction()
{
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }
    $this->loadLayout(false);
    $this->renderLayout();
}

/**
 * Order success action
 */
public function successAction()
{
    $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
    if (!$session->getLastSuccessQuoteId()) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }

    $lastQuoteId = $session->getLastQuoteId();
    $lastOrderId = $session->getLastOrderId();
    $lastRecurringProfiles = $session->getLastRecurringProfileIds();
    if (!$lastQuoteId || (!$lastOrderId && empty($lastRecurringProfiles))) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }

    $session->clear();
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));
    $this->renderLayout();
}

/**
 * Failure action
 */
public function failureAction()
{
    $lastQuoteId = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getLastQuoteId();
    $lastOrderId = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getLastOrderId();

    if (!$lastQuoteId || !$lastOrderId) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}


/**
 * Get additional info action
 */
public function getAdditionalAction()
{
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->_getAdditionalHtml());
}

/**
 * Address JSON
 */
public function getAddressAction()
{
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }
    $addressId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('address', false);
    if ($addressId) {
        $address = $this->getOnepage()->getAddress($addressId);

        if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId() == $address->getCustomerId()) {
            $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-json');
            $this->getResponse()->setBody($address->toJson());
        } else {
            $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','403 Forbidden');
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Save checkout method
 */
public function saveMethodAction()
{
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $method = $this->getRequest()->getPost('method');
        $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveCheckoutMethod($method);
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }
}

/**
 * Save checkout billing address
 */
public function saveBillingAction()
{
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
        $customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing_address_id', false);

        if (isset($data['email'])) {
            $data['email'] = trim($data['email']);
        }
        $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId);

         if (!isset($result['error'])) {

            $method = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';
            $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveShippingMethod($method);
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()-> setShippingMethod($method)->save();

        if (!isset($result['error'])) {
            if ($this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
                $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                $result['update_section'] = array(
                    'name' => 'payment-method',
                    'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                );
            } elseif (isset($data['use_for_shipping']) && $data['use_for_shipping'] == 1) {
                    $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                    $result['update_section'] = array(
                    'name' => 'payment-method',
                    'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                    );

                $result['allow_sections'] = array('shipping');
                $result['duplicateBillingInfo'] = 'true';
            } else {
                $result['goto_section'] = 'shipping';
            }
        }

        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }
    }
}

/**
 * Shipping address save action
 */
public function saveShippingAction()
{
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping', array());
        $customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_address_id', false);
        $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveShipping($data, $customerAddressId);

        if (!isset($result['error'])) {
        $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
        $result['update_section'] = array(
        'name' => 'payment-method',
        'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
    );
     }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }
}

/**
 * Shipping method save action
 */
public function saveShippingMethodAction()
{
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_method', '');
        $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveShippingMethod($data);
        // $result will contain error data if shipping method is empty
        if (!$result) {
            Mage::dispatchEvent(
                'checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method',
                 array(
                      'request' => $this->getRequest(),
                      'quote'   => $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()));
            $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals();
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));

            $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
            $result['update_section'] = array(
                'name' => 'payment-method',
                'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
            );
        }
        $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }
}

/**
 * Save payment ajax action
 *
 * Sets either redirect or a JSON response
 */
public function savePaymentAction()
{
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $this->_ajaxRedirectResponse();
            return;
        }

        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('payment', array());
        $result = $this->getOnepage()->savePayment($data);

        // get section and redirect data
        $redirectUrl = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getPayment()->getCheckoutRedirectUrl();
        if (empty($result['error']) && !$redirectUrl) {
            $this->loadLayout('checkout_onepage_review');
            $result['goto_section'] = 'review';
            $result['update_section'] = array(
                'name' => 'review',
                'html' => $this->_getReviewHtml()
            );
        }
        if ($redirectUrl) {
            $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
        }
    } catch (Mage_Payment_Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getFields()) {
            $result['fields'] = $e->getFields();
        }
        $result['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $result['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
        $result['error'] = $this->__('Unable to set Payment Method.');
    }
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
}

/**
 * Get Order by quoteId
 *
 * @throws Mage_Payment_Model_Info_Exception
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order
 */
protected function _getOrder()
{
    if (is_null($this->_order)) {
        $this->_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getId(), 'quote_id');
        if (!$this->_order->getId()) {
            throw new Mage_Payment_Model_Info_Exception(Mage::helper('core')->__("Can not create invoice. Order was not found."));
        }
    }
    return $this->_order;
}

/**
 * Create invoice
 *
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice
 */
protected function _initInvoice()
{
    $items = array();
    foreach ($this->_getOrder()->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $items[$item->getId()] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
    }
    /* @var $invoice Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Order */
    $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $this->_getOrder())->prepareInvoice($items);
    $invoice->setEmailSent(true)->register();

    Mage::register('current_invoice', $invoice);
    return $invoice;
}

/**
 * Create order action
 */
public function saveOrderAction()
{
    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*');
        return;
    }

    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }

    $result = array();
    try {
        $requiredAgreements = Mage::helper('checkout')->getRequiredAgreementIds();
        if ($requiredAgreements) {
            $postedAgreements = array_keys($this->getRequest()->getPost('agreement', array()));
            $diff = array_diff($requiredAgreements, $postedAgreements);
            if ($diff) {
                $result['success'] = false;
                $result['error'] = true;
                $result['error_messages'] = $this->__('Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order.');
                $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
                return;
            }
        }

        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('payment', array());
        if ($data) {
            $data['checks'] = Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_USE_CHECKOUT
                | Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_USE_FOR_COUNTRY
                | Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_USE_FOR_CURRENCY
                | Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_ORDER_TOTAL_MIN_MAX
                | Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_ZERO_TOTAL;
            $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getPayment()->importData($data);
        }

        $this->getOnepage()->saveOrder();

        $redirectUrl = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getRedirectUrl();
        $result['success'] = true;
        $result['error']   = false;
    } catch (Mage_Payment_Model_Info_Exception $e) {
        $message = $e->getMessage();
        if (!empty($message)) {
            $result['error_messages'] = $message;
        }
        $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
        $result['update_section'] = array(
            'name' => 'payment-method',
            'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
        );
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
        Mage::helper('checkout')->sendPaymentFailedEmail($this->getOnepage()->getQuote(), $e->getMessage());
        $result['success'] = false;
        $result['error'] = true;
        $result['error_messages'] = $e->getMessage();

        $gotoSection = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getGotoSection();
        if ($gotoSection) {
            $result['goto_section'] = $gotoSection;
            $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->setGotoSection(null);
        }
        $updateSection = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getUpdateSection();
        if ($updateSection) {
            if (isset($this->_sectionUpdateFunctions[$updateSection])) {
                $updateSectionFunction = $this->_sectionUpdateFunctions[$updateSection];
                $result['update_section'] = array(
                    'name' => $updateSection,
                    'html' => $this->$updateSectionFunction()
                );
            }
            $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->setUpdateSection(null);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
        Mage::helper('checkout')->sendPaymentFailedEmail($this->getOnepage()->getQuote(), $e->getMessage());
        $result['success']  = false;
        $result['error']    = true;
        $result['error_messages'] = $this->__('There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later.');
    }
    $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();
    /**
     * when there is redirect to third party, we don't want to save order yet.
     * we will save the order in return action.
     */
    if (isset($redirectUrl)) {
        $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
    }

    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
}

/**
 * Filtering posted data. Converting localized data if needed
 *
 * @param array
 * @return array
 */
protected function _filterPostData($data)
{
    $data = $this->_filterDates($data, array('dob'));
    return $data;
}

/**
 * Check can page show for unregistered users
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
protected function _canShowForUnregisteredUsers()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()
        || $this->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'index'
        || Mage::helper('checkout')->isAllowedGuestCheckout($this->getOnepage()->getQuote())
        || !Mage::helper('checkout')->isCustomerMustBeLogged();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. Your code is working.. But now i have stucked in a different problem... the shipping method step is removed from the checkout page.. but its not getting continue after the billing information.. Do you have any idea how to proceed from billing information to the shipping information as well as payment information after filling up the fields... ??

Answer (score 0):

Please verify this function : `protected function _canShowForUnregisteredUsers()`
you have forgotten to finish function with closing bracket.

Comment: Yes Its right...but the error is showing on the ' public function saveShippingMethodAction() '....  can you check what is it ??

Comment: In above function "saveBillingAction()", you need to add one closing bracket in proper place according to your code. Please maintain hierarchy in that function, so your problem will get solved.